# How do I import a CSV file?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to using Python and Pandas and I am trying to import a CSV or text file to an array with quotes in between the issues like

```
sp500 = ['appl', 'ibm', 'csco']

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\data\\stock.txt', index_col=[0])

df
```

which gets me:

```
Out[20]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [AAPL, IBM, CSCO]
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What have you read/tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I can never get the `code` thing to work right.  I have only tried to do a basic import and get it into an array but I can't get the  '   ' around each issue.

Comment: Please show a few lines of the `stock.txt` file.  What is the problem with what you're getting?  Where does `sp500` fit into the question/answer?

Comment: As for indenting code, write it as you want it to appear, without tabs.  Paste it into the edit box, select it, then press the **`{}`** button above the edit box.

Comment: Below is the sample list of like 150 stocks that I want to scan in a index.  I am defining the list after I import the classes and methods.  I am trying to get the 150 stocks formatted like the sp500 array at the top.  I can use csv, txt or excel.  I would just like to not have to do the whole thing be hand or with vi or something.  Since its for a matplotlib/pandas 1st project I thought I would try to do it all in the same environment. ---------------------
AAPL
FB
BAC
TWTR
YHOO
PBR

Comment: i cannot see the sample list. What should the result look like? What is `sp500` useful for?

Comment: I was trying to loop through a list of stocks to compare indicator value.  I found a sentdex video that showed what I was try to do.  Thank you everyone for your replies.  I'll try to make future post clearer.  `code`{import numpy as np

def main():

    try:
        issue = np.loadtxt('C:\\data\\stock.txt',delimiter=',',unpack=True,dtype='str')

        print issue

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)}